# ERROR 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails on DELETE operation?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to `DELETE` a record from db (mySQL Workbench) and I get the constraints error.

```
Executing:
DELETE FROM `users` WHERE (`ID` = '27');

Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
ERROR 1452: 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`people`, CONSTRAINT `people_ibfk_36` FOREIGN KEY (`creatorID`) REFERENCES `users` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
SQL Statement:
DELETE FROM `users` WHERE (`ID` = '27')
```

What can be the cause of the error? Shouldn't the database just cascade delete whatever is referenced to `users` for the deleted record (in this case entries in the `people` table)? Can this be caused by some further references (that eg. would set null on delete and null is not allowed), but the error points to the nearest table in the reference chain?

EDIT: table definitions

`Users` table

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `firstLogin` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `surname` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `createdAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updatedAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `accountTypeID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `accountTypeID` (`accountTypeID`),
  CONSTRAINT `users_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`accountTypeID`) REFERENCES `account_types` (`ID`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=29 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

`People` table

```
CREATE TABLE `people` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `appOwner` tinyint(1) DEFAULT 0,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `surname` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `createdAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updatedAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `favStatusID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `userID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `creatorID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL  
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `people_creator_i_d_user_i_d` (`creatorID`,`userID`),
  KEY `favStatusID` (`favStatusID`),
  KEY `userID` (`userID`),
  CONSTRAINT `people_ibfk_34` FOREIGN KEY (`favStatusID`) REFERENCES `fav_statuses` (`ID`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `people_ibfk_35` FOREIGN KEY (`userID`) REFERENCES `users` (`ID`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `people_ibfk_36` FOREIGN KEY (`creatorID`) REFERENCES `users` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=200 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: Please publish both table definitions.

Comment: This means that you try to delete a row on the side "one", and no cascade ON DELETE operation is defined.

Comment: @P.Salmon I added the definitions.

Comment: @Akina So this line is the culprit from `people` definition?  `CONSTRAINT people_ibfk_35 FOREIGN KEY (userID) REFERENCES users (ID) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE`?  I don't want to cascade delete `user` when deleting `person`, but the other way round yes.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. I suggest you find every people row where userid or creatorid = 27 and see if that gives you some idea. I would be interested to see all unique combinations where userid or creatorid = 27

Comment: @P.Salmon I can not delete any `user` record. Each `user` has an entry in `people` where `people.userID` = `people.creatorID` (= `users.ID`). Maybe this forms some kind of circular dependency?